# How do I unlock Iron Wizard mode?

Tags: gemcraft-chasing-shadows

According to Steam, the most elusive achievement is beating the game in Iron Wizard mode. This mode has a way lower skill-point cap than the normal play mode (because there's no wizard XP, just 5 skill points per beaten level).

I can't seem to figure out how to unlock this iron wizard mode though. What do I need to do to unlock this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you pass Wizard Level 100 on a regular save the Iron Wizard mode will unlock. Simply start a new game and select the Iron Wizard option to continue.